# Can't navigate to role name from IdentityUserRole in Identity v2

Tags: asp.net-identity

Prior to ASP Identity v2, you could do this..

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

var role = context.Users.FirstOrDefault().Roles.Single(p => p.Role.Name == "Some role name");
```

As soon as I upgraded to Identity v2, lines like this in my application stopped compiling. There is no longer a Role property on IdentityUserRole, so it's not easy to, for example, find all users in the "Administrators" role.

I know there are other methods of finding users in a role, but my needs are different. This is a simplified example, but I need to construct a specific list of users with specific role information, sorta like this:

```
var data = context.Users.Select(p => new
{
    Administrator = p.Roles.Any(role => role.Role.Name == "Administrator"),
    ServiceProvider = p.Roles.Any(role => role.Role.Name == "ServiceProvider"),
    Lender = p.Roles.Any(role => role.Role.Name == "Lender"),
    Inspector = p.Roles.Any(role => role.Role.Name == "Inspector")
});
```

It doesn't appear as if that kind of query is possible any more with Identity v2.

Comment: Did you get a solution for the issue?

Comment: I haven't had time to get back to this project, but the temporary fix seems simple. You can still do something like p.Roles.Any(role => role.RoleId == 3). You have to look up the role id first.

Answer (score 1):

We will likely be adding a new helper method on the role manager to get all users in a role.  We couldn't keep navigation properties on both User and Role because that would have resulted in a circular reference of two generic types. This should be added in version 2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, Hao. I'll post my work-around as soon as I have an opportunity.